# Why are subsequent downloads with youtube-dl so much faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

I am downloading and converting multiple YouTube videos to audio only files on my RPi Zero. While the init and first download take quite some time, subsequent downloads are way faster. Is there any way to "warm up" yt-dl to be faster even for the first download? I don't mind any additional initialization time.
(Changing the order of the URLs has no effect.)

```py
import time
t1 = time.time()

from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
ydl = YoutubeDL({'format': 'bestaudio/best'}) 
t2 = time.time()
print(t2 - t1, flush=True)

ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxx'])
t3 = time.time()
print(t3 - t2, flush=True)

ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyyyyyyyyyy'])
t4 = time.time()
print(t4 - t3, flush=True)

ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzzzzzzzzzz',])
t5 = time.time()
print(t5 - t4, flush=True)
```

Output:

```
5.889932870864868
[youtube] xxxxxxxxxxx: Downloading webpage
[download] 100% of 4.09MiB in 00:01
15.685529470443726
[youtube] yyyyyyyyyyy: Downloading webpage
[download] 100% of 3.58MiB in 00:00
2.526634693145752
[youtube] zzzzzzzzzzz: Downloading webpage
[download] 100% of 3.88MiB in 00:01
2.4716105461120605
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stepping through the youtube-dl code I found that most of the time is consumed for finding the correct `InfoExtractor` for YT URLs. When downloading the first media item the framework goes through hundreds of possible extractors (with regular expression execution on each one) and finally settles at the correct YT extractor which is on position **1122** in my case!

This is my quick hack that completely removes 12 seconds from the process on my RPi Zero:

```py
import time
timer = time.time()

from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

ydl = YoutubeDL({'format': 'bestaudio/best'})

# Get correct info extractor and replace the long existing list
ydl._ies = [ydl.get_info_extractor('Youtube')]

print(time.time() - timer)
timer = time.time()

# Super fast first download, yay!
ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxx'])

print(time.time() - timer)
```

Output:

```
5.961918592453003
[youtube] xxxxxxxxxxx: Downloading webpage
[download] 100% of 4.09MiB in 00:01
3.7426917552948   <-- way faster!
```

Maybe there is a more regular way for this without overwriting semi private variables.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this should do.  D/L's info from each vid, then retrieves those vids.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import time
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

##  opts = { 'format': 'best[height<=720,ext=mp4]/best[height<=720]' }
opts = { 'format': 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestaudio/best' }

ydl = YoutubeDL( opts )

videos = [ 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVsQLlk-T0s',
           'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3l2oi-X8P38',
           'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPpcfH_HHH8' ]

items = []

for video in videos:
    timer = time .time()
    info = ydl .extract_info( video,  download = False )
    items .append( info )
    print( 'info:',  info['title'],  '--',  time .time() -timer,  flush = True )

for item in items:
    timer = time .time()
    ydl .process_video_result( item )
    print( 'vid:',  item['title'],  '--',  time .time() -timer,  flush = True )
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps in the sense that I know now how to retrieve media infos without downloading the actual content. So for my needs I would have to get the infos for a random video and afterwards downloads are all pretty fast. Not exactly what I was looking for, but I can probably work with that.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can speed that up without getting faster internet service.  That's network-time, negotiating secure sockets with YouTube.

Possibly, you can speed it up *some* by testing the speed of your current DNS and see if there's a faster one available.

https://www.serverwatch.com/guides/two-tools-for-testing-dns-server-speeds

Comment: Thank you for the response. I wouldn't mind the time for socket negotiating if it would happen before I try to download media. Is there any way to make yt-dl do that beforehand?

EDIT: something like `ydl.init_socket(...)` would be very helpful...

Comment: I just found out that network stuff is not the bottleneck here, see my answer. Thanks anyway for your input!